# Issues with Openlayers 7.10 Workshop npm start fails

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, npm-start

I am trying to create a web application using geoserver + open layers. I have my geoserver working well so I am moving on to open layers.

I am trying to go through the [workshop](https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/) to familiarize myself with it, but I can't get past the

`npm start`

I enter it into the cmd prompt and then receive the following

`C:\Users\john22>npm start

npm ERR! Missing script: "start"

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?

npm ERR! npm star # Mark your favorite packages

npm ERR! npm stars # View packages marked as favorites

npm ERR!

npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:

npm ERR! npm run`

I have done some googling and looking on the stack exchange but it seems like it should have been a file that was downloaded with the installation package.

I have also tried following along with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGak-5dCvHM&list=PLatjyVcZFWJqCgDMn_PLHbU3crn3g8kRs&index=9) but when I get to 41:20 I do not have the ol file and I also am not sure where I would even put them since I don't have Apache on my C drive like in the video (I am using Geoserver 2.21.2 which does not require Tomcat). I am working on a Windows VCL

I have tried using version 6.15 of Open layers as well

Comment: I just downloaded the workshop and every worked fine. did you install all npm packages? did you start you cmd in the right folder?

Comment: npm needs to be executed in the project root folder with the file package.json in it.

Comment: @sebastian Where are all the npm packages? I've downloaded everything from https://github.com/openlayers/workshop/releases, node 18.12, and geoserver 7.10. I was able to do npm install in the cmd prompt and that ran with no errors.